# What is better to do on Shabbos HaGodol?

Tags: passover, shabbat, challah-shabbat-bread, matzah

Is it better to eat egg Matza at the Seuda or is it better to eat Challa at the Seuda? What are the pros and cons of either choice?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about where the 1st night of Pesach is Motzei Shabbos?

Comment: Actually not! I am talking in a year like this year.

Comment: @Gershon then why not just eat Challa? There's plenty of time to clean...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Challah:

Pros = *oneg Shabbos*, For sure a *seuda* as long as you eat a *kizayis*

Con  = Hametz which causes stress for neurotic housewives on almost *erev Pesah*

Egg Matzoh:

Pro: Not Hametz and therefore does not cause stress for neurotic housewives on almost *erev Pesah*

Cons: Not really *oneg Shabbos* when compared to Challah (unless you have strange taste or bad Challah), In order to for sure be a *kevias seudah* and require *HaMotzi* and *Bircas hamazon* according to all opinions you would need to eat 4 or 5 *kebeitzos* of it.

Hashem told us that Pesah (regarding *issur hametz*) starts on the 14th of Nisan, in the afternoon. Why should we add more than what *Hazal* saw fit to add to that time? Get the ladies some psychotherapy and let us men enjoy our Shabbos *seudos* the way they were meant to be!

Comment: Shloshim yom achar hachag sho'alim v'dorshim b'ofi hachag?

Comment: Mishenichnas Adar marbin besimha ve'ain mema'atin besimha ad shenichnas Av! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Yet another possibility: use challah, but eat it on your porch or whatever, away from the Shabbos table. Then return to the table and eat the rest of the (Pesachdik) meal. That is what my family and I do.